# Storing information, like alphas and which methods were called, in Spritekit

Tags: objective-c, delegates, sprite-kit, nsuserdefaults, skscene

I am still amateur. I want to save information in the `SettingsScene` when I press the home button. This information includes `alpha` of each button and the game should know that the methods like `defaultModePlay` (check `sendInformationAboutDefaultChallenge` and `SettingsScene.h`) were called. I hope you can follow my code below. Please bear with me if this code looks silly, your advice is highly welcomed.

In simpler terms: I want to store information (maybe using `NSUserDefaults`) from the `SettingsScene`. Is there any way I can do that?

This is how the `delegate` is set in the `SettingsScene`...

```
@class SettingsScene;

@protocol SettingsSceneDelegate <NSObject>

@required

-(void)defaultModePlay;
-(void)mediumModePlay;
-(void)hardModePlay;

@end

@interface SettingsScene : SKScene

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SettingsSceneDelegate, SKSceneDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

this is a method in SettingsScene.m

```
-(void)sendInformationAboutDefaultChallenge
{
    [self.delegate defaultModePlay];
}
```

touchBegan method in game `SettingsScene.m` and these are buttons that when pressed, their `alpha`s change and they should call methods that are set in the `SettingsScene.h`.These methods send information to `gameScene` which control the speed of particles.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"DefaultChallengeMode"]) {
        defaultChallengeButton.alpha = 0.5;
        mediumChallengeButton.alpha = 1.0;
        hardChallengeButton.alpha = 1.0;

        // the game should play the default way of playing.

        [self sendInformationAboutDefaultChallenge];
    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"MediumChallengeMode"]) {
        mediumChallengeButton.alpha = 0.5;
        defaultChallengeButton.alpha = 1.0;
        hardChallengeButton.alpha = 1.0;

    }
    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"hardChallengingMode"]) {
        hardModeButton.alpha = 0.5;
        defaultModeButton.alpha = 1.0;
        mediumModeButton.alpha = 1.0;

    }

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"home"]) {

        // save what ever happened in this scene

    }

}
```

In the `gameScene`, I have the method from `SettingsScene`...

```
-(void)defaultModePlay
{
    defaultGame = YES;
}
```

Maybe I should store information from the `gameScene`, I don't know.
I have not shown these methods here..., but I hope you can follow...

```
-(void)mediumModePlay;
-(void)hardModePlay;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to capture the state of every UI element, why not simply store the difficulty mode and use that to determine how the UI should be displayed? I would first put the difficulty modes into an `enum` (see [this article](http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/) for the best way to do that) and then store them in `NSUserDefaults`. That will look something like `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:difficultyLevel forKey:@"difficultyLevel"]`.

Comment: :I want the button to show that it was previously pressed when the user comes back to the settings, thats why I wanted to store `alpha`s. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Which button are you referring to? If it's a difficulty button (the only ones in the code you posted), that would be pretty easy to determine based on the saved difficulty setting.